# react-bootstrap Form component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I have tried several times to use the `<Form>` and `<FormControl>` components. Everytime I use I keep getting same erros:

> "warning.js?8a56:45 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be
>   null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM
>   elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render
>   method of `App`."
>
> "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `App`."

Even with this basic example:

```jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, Checkbox, Radio, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <FormGroup controlId="formControlsText">
          <ControlLabel>Text</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Enter text" />
        </FormGroup>

        <Button type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you updated the npm package to the latest version, i believe those components are new for react-bootstrap.

Comment: which version are you referring to?

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer so this can be closed.

Comment: @JazzCat please add you comment as answer so that the question doesn't appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

Update the npm-package those components are new in react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Import your React-Bootstrap components like this:

```
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControl';
```

That helped me to get rid of the same error when using react-bootstrap 0.31.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat related issue and discovered they removed `ControlLabel` replacing it with `FormLabel` in more recent versions.

Change

```
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, etc... } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

To

```
import {FormControl, FormGroup, FormLabel, etc... } from 'react-bootstrap';
```